# Getting RegExp source without "beforhand" and "afterward" patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have such a constant object:

```
export const Roles = {
  match: {
    Applicant: /^applicant$/,
    Employee: /^employee$/,
    Default: /^default-roles/,
  },
  value: {
    Applicant: 'applicant',
    Employee: 'employee',
  },
};
```

I want to be able to get rid of `Roles#match` and `Roles#value` keys to be simply like:

```
export const Roles = {
    Applicant: /^applicant$/,
    Employee: /^employee$/,
    Default: /^default-roles/,
};
```

so I found `RegExp.source`. It does remove `/` but not other flags like `^` and `$`